# js: how to run pain text as javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where user can type some javascript logic and then i have to run it

Basically what i want is:

```
function custommethod(value){

............
Now i have to use the user provided code here
.........
eg:
var something = value + 2
return something
.............
user code ends
.............

}
```

So the user code will be

```
var something = value + 2
return something
```

then later i run the function withe the user logic and get the return value

how can i do this

Comment: You may check [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) but it is discouraged to use it due to high security risk.

Comment: but will it run custom code with multiple lines

Comment: It will run all lines of code you provide. But if it functions like a function body, you should check [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) instead. This one is also discouraged to use for the same reason

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp
Eval function seems to be the answer to this question. Visit the for a quick example.